# Setup login through Docker API in Python

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-api

I'm trying Docker API python library, but couldn't get a little success, have go through the docs.Actually I'm trying to login to docker using API.

Here's my python Code:

```
import docker

config = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'IGui') + 'config.json'
client = docker.APIClient.login('username', '*******', 'email@gmail.com','https://index.docker.io/v1/', config)
```

Here's the error I received:

```
AttributeError at /gui/docker/
'str' object has no attribute '_auth_configs'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/gui/docker/
Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute '_auth_configs'
Exception Location: /Users/abdul/IstioVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-     packages/docker/api/daemon.py in login, line 128
Python Executable:  /Users/abdul/IstioVirEnv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.1
```

how can I setup docker login through API in python? help me please!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the command you are trying to run: http://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html#docker.client.DockerClient.login

From the docs, I see the parameters you pass are:

- username = 'username'
- password = '********'
- email = 'email@gmail.com'
- registry = 'https://index.docker.io/v1/'
- reauth = config <- which is a string, maybe this is the issue?
- dockercfg_path = not given

I'm not sure, it could be you're using an older/newer version of the module. Try using keyword arguments. That might help narrow it down.

Comment: I'm confused about reauth & dockercfg arguments, is there any example on how to accomplish login using docker API in python?

Comment: `reauth` is a boolean. dockerdfg_path is a string. Since you passed a string I assume you are trying to pass dockercfg_path. But the 4th positional argument is supposed to be `reauth` (a boolean). That may be the issue.

Comment: when I pass `'False'` for  **reauth** it still through the same error as: `'str' object has no attribute '_auth_configs'`

Comment: what I need to pass instead of **reauth**  &  **dockercfg_path**  ?